# Background images jump when opening modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, scrollbar, background-image

I build a page with a parallax effect and an image gallery using Bootstrap 4. 
The problem is that the background image jumps/resizes when I open a modal and I feel like I tried everything to fix this.
BS does a good job keeping all other elements where they are, scrollbar or not, but not the background image.

<

```js
// call ekko-lightbox
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body,
html,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  color: #666666;
}

.bgimg-1 {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/005/540/665/large/thorsten-erdt-nami-small.jpg?1491824822");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">

<body>
  <header class="container-fluid h-100 bgimg-1" id="home">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col col-sm-auto text-white text-center">
        <h2 class="d-md-none">ART OF</h2>
        <h2 class="bg-dark d-block">THORSTEN ERDT</h2>
        <h2 class="d-none d-md-block">ILLUSTRATION</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="container" id="editorial">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <a href="IMG" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="img-gallery"><img src="thumbnail" alt="captiontext1" style="width:50px"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
```

If I set

```
background-size:{auto;}
background-position: {left top;}
```

it wont jump anymore, but it wont resize for smaller devices either, so that wont do.

If I set

```
overflow-y:{scroll;}
```

it still adds padding to everything which results in everything jumping...

```
body.modal-open {padding:0;}
```

fixes that, but now the navbar is the only thing jumping. Oh and of course I can scroll the page while the modal is open, too.

If someone has another idea how to fix this I am all ears.

Comment: The problem seems to be in `background: fixed cover` If I put the bg image(s) on the html element it actually fits the entire screen including the scrollbar so it stops resizing. Sadly this seems to cause problems with bootstrap or sth else since the navbar links start bugging out and scrollspy stops working, too AND I'd need to replace the background img via js to get a parallax effect with multiple bg images.  
I tried using `width:100vw` on html, body and the original div but the bg-img only ignores the scrollbar when applied to the html element.

Answer (score 4):

When you open a `bootstrap-modal`, It will remove vertical scroll if you have, So you feel like your background image is jumping. And it is feature.

If you want to override it's css , you can add following code at the end of your css.

```
 .modal-open {
   overflow-y: inherit;  
 }
```

It is better to use `overflow-y : inherit` instead of using `overflow-y : scroll` as described below:

```
 .modal-open {
   overflow-y: scroll;  
 }
```

See it is working in [**Demo**](https://jsbin.com/votemixana/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

**Edit:**

```
 .modal-open{
  padding:0 !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

Add the above code in your css. and all your problem solved. For more details: [**Click me**](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1599)

Hope this solution will work for you. 
If you have any doubts, comment in comment section.

Comment: Is there a reason "inherit" is supposedly better than "scroll"?

Comment: yes @Thornos, `inherit` will add scroll if your page has scrolling, but in case if your page doesn't contain scroll, and if you add `overflow-y:scroll` then it will add scrolling.

Comment: Regarding the code: I do understand that it's a feature from BS to use padding to compensate for the removal of the scrollbar, which works fine for everything except background images.  
`.modal.open: {overflow-y:inherit;}` has the same result as `scroll`. Everything **except** the background image jumps around now.  
`body.modal-open {padding:0 !important;}` fixes that, except for the navbar, which still jumps around (not shown in the code snippet)  
Iwonder if there's no way to finish the BS compensation feature so that the background is fixed as well?

Comment: @Thornos, i edited my answer. see more details if you needed.

Comment: After some testing I found that to keep the bootstrap navbar from jumping around I had to add `class=px-0` to the navbar, if you have centered content in there.

Comment: I'm using @material-ui in a React project. This issue was tough since I was targeting the `html` element for the background image. Either the image - or the React app would jump when opening a modal. My solution was to target the `body` tag, and apply the "Edit" styles mentioned above. Thanks @yash!